# Calculate subtotal and total with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add two values together. The value of #price and the value of #subtotal. Subtotal is being calculated with the Jquery script and is working. The other script isn't working but does work on its own.

The div's #price, #subtotal and #total must be div's and cannot be changed into text fields with value.

**Code:**

```js
/* JQUERY */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#checkboxdiv input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#checkboxdiv input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });
    $('#subtotal').text(total);
  });
});

/* JAVASCRIPT */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#total").append(addnumbers($("#price").html(), $("#subtotal").html()));
});

function addnumbers(price, subtotal) {
  return (Number(price) + Number(subtotal));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price">10500</div>

<div id="checkboxdiv">
  <input type="checkbox" value="300">Optie 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="750">Optie 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="25">Optie 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="1200">Optie 4
</div>

<div id="subtotal"></div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using two `$(document).ready()` seperately. The code will  be much cleaner if you put it all together.

Comment: Please explain a bit more "_The other script isn't working_". What is supposed to happen? What is happening now?

Comment: Debug your code. Chrome has verry good debugging tools. Just add a breakpoint and see what happens. Also if your code is not working do not inline function calls ( $("#total").append(addnumbers($("#price").html(),$("#subtotal").html()));)

Comment: Subtotal has no valid innerhtml upon document.ready, so you try to add 10500 to null, which should still return 10500, but probably not what you intended.

Comment: What I want is a calculation with Jquery or javascript to calculate the subtotal and the total. The subtotal is all the checked checkboxes together and the total is the subtotal and the price together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understand what you want... I guess is that when you click a checkbox, subtotal and total are updated. If that's the case, you can do it with....

```
$("#checkboxdiv input:checkbox").change(function() {

    var subtotal = 0;

    $('#checkboxdiv input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        subtotal += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });

    $('div#subtotal').text(subtotal);
    $('div#total').text(parseInt($('div#price').text()) + subtotal);
});

// If you want to show the initial values, just trigger the event.
$("#checkboxdiv input:checkbox").trigger('change');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason you are not seeing the `div#total` change is because it is not subscribed to the checkbox changes, whereas `div#subtotal` is. I combined the contents of the two document ready functions, moved the `div#total` into the change listener, and it's working as expected.

See CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxjYBd

The combined code:

```
function addnumbers(price,subtotal){
  return (Number(price) + Number(subtotal));
};

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#checkboxdiv input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#checkboxdiv input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });

    $('#subtotal').text(total);
    $("#total").text(addnumbers($("#price").html(), $("#subtotal").html()));
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.